# Selenium IE 32bit WebDriver is crashing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Have a strange happening with Selenium and the WebDriver - using the IE Webdriver 32bit - when ever the following code is executed; on the second for the Web Driver crashes with the following:

```
Command line server for the IE driver has stopped working
```

The Java code is as follows:

```
// Del Language and add one
for (int j = 1; j <= 18; j++) {
    WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title,'Delete Language')]"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title,'Delete Language')]")).click();
}
```

and the Console Log is as follows:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
    Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
    System info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64',     os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at pw_Test_Automation.Update_Offender_Details.main(Update_Offender_Details.java:179)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:66)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

There will might be a browser compatibly issue of the website you are calling in `driver.get("................");`
First try to open this url normally in IE without selenium or try some other url to open in IE. This will help to clarify that the problem exist in which part.

Comment: Don't think there is an issue with the Driver.Get("......") as there is code that runs prior to this part, and runs with no issue - seems to fail when on the 3rd For Loop.... really weird - works okay in FF and Chrome....